# RDP into server with specific username

Tags: powershell, arguments, rdp, start-process

I need to be able to call the exe and specify the servername and username only. I still want it to prompt for the password like normal. When I call the first command below the RDP will prompt me for my password, but it already has my local username inserted. If I wanted to use some one else's username, I can't get it to work correctly in the second command.

```
Start-Process "$env:windir\system32\mstsc.exe" -ArgumentList "/v:$server"

Start-Process "$env:windir\system32\mstsc.exe" -ArgumentList "/v:$server/IP:$username"
```

How do I pass in just the servername and the username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mstsc.exe` does not have a `/username` parameter.  It does, however, have a `/prompt` argument which will prompt for username and password.  Otherwise, you need to use a `.rdp` connection file.

---

Update:
You can utilize `cmdkey` to preload credentials so `mstsc` does not prompt you when you remote into a host, and then prompt for credentials using built-in functionality such as `Read-Host` or `Get-Credential` yourself.

Example function:

```
function Connect-Host
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Connection -ComputerName $PSItem -Quiet})]
        [string]
        $ComputerName,

        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [System.Management.Automation.CredentialAttribute()]
        [pscredential]
        $Credential = (Get-Credential)
    )

    $cmdKeyArgs = @(
        "/generic:TERMSRV/$ComputerName"
        "/user:$($Credential.UserName)"
        "/pass:$($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)"
    )
    $null = & "$Env:SystemRoot\System32\CMDKEY.exe" @cmdKeyArgs

    & "$Env:SystemRoot\System32\MSTSC.exe" /v:$ComputerName
}
```

This can be modified so it doesn't prompt you every time you run it since it will cache your credentials with `cmdkey`.  Additional logic can be used to query `cmdkey` for the computer you're connecting to prior to prompting/saving.

Example of this:

```
cmdkey /list |
    Select-String -Pattern $ComputerName -Context 2 |
    Select-Object -Property @(
         @{N='ComputerName';E={$ComputerName}}
         @{N='User';E={$PSItem.Context.PostContext[-1] -replace '\s*User:\s*'}}
    )
```

Comment: So there's no way I can specify a username for the RDP to use without having an .rdp file?

Comment: @CuriousOne Correct.

Comment: I just tried this on my Win10 laptop. Doesn't really work. Or at least not the way I wanted it to. I wanted it to prompt for BOTH user name AND password. But  adding `/prompt` to the mstsc.exe call doesn't actually force a username prompt. It still has the user name prefilled with what I used the previous time to connect. And I manually have to first click the `More choices` link and then the `Use a different account`link to get to the user name prompt.

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff It's been a while, but I'm going to update this answer with a solution I've come up with in the past year.  See my edit now

Comment: @CuriousOne If you're still active, I've updated this answer to meet your use-case better.